# Combine two ffmpeg commands

Tags: unix, ffmpeg

Is there a way to combine the following two ffmpeg commands into one?

```
ffmpeg -i OutputAudioEN.mp4  -acodec aac -strict -2 german.mp4
ffmpeg -i german.mp4 -c copy -f segment 
       -segment_list audio-de.m3u8 -segment_time 10 output%03d.ts
```

Is this possible to use the output from the first command for the second line, without using two separate commands?

Comment: This works for me.
`ffmpeg -i OutputAudioEN.mp4 -f segment -segment_list audio-de.m3u8 -segment_time 10 -acodec aac -strict -2 output%03d.ts`

Comment: @Chamath You can make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here I'm making my comment as a proper answer. What I'm suggesting here is you can directly segment the video and then encode the audio using `acc` according to your need. Following command works for me.

```
ffmpeg -i OutputAudioEN.mp4 -f segment -segment_list audio-de.m3u8 -segment_time 10 -acodec aac -strict -2 output%03d.ts
```

Like this you can segment the video while audio encoding also happens at the meantime.

Hope this helps you!